Is this mallard transitioning out of breeding plumage?
Is this  mallard transitioning from conspicuous to ordinary plumage, or is there a different reason for why its colours seem patchy?
It was photographed in Vienna during late September.


Mallards go through moult once a year. They do this at a different time for females and males, the former one during the nesting season (somewhere between February and May), for the males this happens between June and August after the mating season.
In this time they lose all of their colorful feathers as well as the ability to fly for 3-4 weeks, in this time the look similar in coat color to the females which gives them better chances to hide. After this period the colorful feathers start to grow again, giving the bird a patchy look which is called "eclipse plumage" by ornithologists.
In September the bird you photographed is on its way back to full color, that's why it is looking so different.
The sequence looks like this (source):


So it is the complete opposite of what I thought! Instead of the period of bright plumage being brief, it is the period of inconspicuous appearance! Thank you!

So the males, in moult, look similar to females?

They lose all of their colourful feathers because they come loose.

What is the evolutionary benefit of this? If the colorful plumage was only for the short breeding period and the simpler one for the rest of the year, I could understand it. But why is the "stealthy" period so brief, and why do they regain their colorful mating plumage long before the next breeding season?

@EndAntisemiticHate Yes, they do, except for the beak: This is bright yellow in males.

@vsz They need to renew their feathers and they need some camouflage in this time, because they cannot fly. When they change back to normal color they go through a second (partial) moult, but retain their ability to fly. So only a short period is needed.

Wow. Thanks.  I've learned much over the years on Stack Exchange sites, but frankly, I think this may be the most surprising!
